# Error Visual studio code can't find command 'CodeGPT: Set API Key' resulted in an error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use the CodeGPT extension but when I look for API Key part, VS code gives an error

> command 'codegpt.setApiKeyCodeGPT' not found

, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I also get this error - you can workaround it by doing the following:

1. Press `cmd+shift+p` to bring up the code pallete
2. Search `Ask CodeGPT`, and select it
3. Write a question (it doesn't matter what it is, it won't be sent)
4. CodeGPT will prompt you for your API key

---

Answer sourced from a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/davila7/code-gpt-docs/issues/24#issuecomment-1406642177) regarding the problem.

Comment: it worked, appreciate it